# "Stupidity" or "Stupidness" - What should I use? Can I use either of them?

Tags: word-usage, pejorative-language

I got into a debate with a colleague when I said "Look at this level of stupidness" and he said "It's not stupidness, it's stupidity".

Here I am, trying to win a debate.

Comment: Both are in the OED, with the same meaning. But *stupidness* is stated now to be 'rare'. It quotes no examples since 1725.

Comment: If you want to use non-standard English, you can also use "stupid" as a noun. For example "the stupid, it burns".

Comment: You could use "stupidness" over "stupidity" as part of a line of an uneducated character, to underline their own *stupidity*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***Stupidity*** dates back to the 16th century and has always been the more common term. ***Stupidness*** appears to be a later variant which actually has always been used rarely.

*Stupidity vs stupidness:*

> - As nouns the difference between stupidness and stupidity is that stupidness is rare but both refer to  the quality or state of being stupid.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stupidness%2Cstupidity&year_start=1650&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstupidness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstupidity%3B%2Cc0): *stupidity vs stupidness*.

According to the Oxford Dictionary Online ***[stupidness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/stupidness)*** is mainly a *West Indian* usage:

> (Mass noun) *chiefly West Indian*
>   - Foolish or nonsensical talk or behaviour:
>   girl, what stupidness are you talking?

and the [Dictionary of Caribbean English Usage](https://books.google.it/books?id=PmvSk13sIc0C&pg=PA537&dq=%22stupidness%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIwvHfkqzyxwIVhj4UCh2-Gwoi#v=onepage&q=%22stupidness%22&f=false) offers a few examples of its usage such as:

> - Nonsense; stupid thinking; an absurdity, a. We asked Mr James to attend a Conference, just a feu: months ago that teas. He said he was not able to go. *He is the President of the Senate and to talk stupidness like that around this table around*...

[Stupidity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stupidity&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - 1540s, "want of intelligence," from Latin stupiditatem (nominative stupiditas) "dullness, stupidity, senselessness," from stupidus "confounded, amazed; dull, foolish" (see stupid). It also at various times meant "lack of feeling or emotion" (1560s); "stupor, numbness" (c. 1600).

[-ity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ity&searchmode=none) (suffix):

> - ***suffix forming abstract nouns from adjectives, meaning "condition or quality of being ______,"*** from Middle English -ite, from Old French -ité and directly from Latin -itatem (nominative -itas), suffix denoting state or condition, composed of connective -i- + -tas.

Comment: As you give the etymology of "-ity", it's interesting to compare it with "[-ness](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ness)": it mostly boils down to the old Romantic vs Germanic origin distinction. ("-ity" being Romantic, and "-ness" being Germanic.) Though as "[stupid](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stupid)" is derived from Latin, "stupidness" would technically be a mixed formation.

Comment: @R.M. I don't think anyone frowns on mixed formations of English and Latin; I've only heard criticism of mixing Latin and Greek roots. Another example like this is "relationship" or "companionship."

Answer (score 8):

Both are in the OED, with the same meaning.

But ***stupidness*** is stated now to be **'rare'**. It quotes no examples since 1725.

Certainly my own inclination would be for ***stupidity***

Answer (score 1):

I am from the West Indies,  Trinidad to be exact and when we use the term stupidness it refers to an act of stupidity.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, do you have an external source to support your answer?

Comment: Finding a source might be difficult, but on our EL&U site an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Is there a book, newspaper or magazine that might have this usage? At the very least, can you give more context to who "we" represents, e.g. is it purely a family or neighbourhood thing, or a broader suburban colloquialism, or a standard Trinidadian usage across most levels of society?

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Trinidad. The whole society uses the term stupidness. Generally you would hear people say "what kind of stupidness is this" or, "he/she is always involved in stupidness". The word stupidness is part of the lexicon in Trinidad.