# Stupid and/or stupidly

Tags: nouns, adjectives, adverbs

As I understand the word 'stupid' is used as a noun, an adjective and as an adverb.
However there is also the word '*stupidly*' of which I think that's the proper adverb, but it is hardly used. Common is '*he is driving 'stupid*' and not '*he is driving 'stupidly*'. Which is correct ?

My second question is about the nouns *stupid, stupidity and stupidness*. I understand that one can call someone '*a stupid*'. Please explain the difference between *stupidity and stupidness*, if any.

Comment: I would say "driving stupidly", not "driving stupid", and the brief web search I did turned up more results for the former than for the latter.

Comment: I would say that "He's driving stupid" is much less common than "He's driving, stupid" with the comma indicating that 'stupid' is an derogatory form of address directed at a third person rather than a description of the driving style. It could be used, for example in the conversation "Why isn't he answering his phone?" "He's driving, stupid!" The word 'stupid' is only used as an adjective informally and, I would argue, incorrectly.

Comment: *-ly* is sometimes (often) dropped. This has already been answered before. See related previous posts. Good Luck.

Comment: Driving stupid is similar to driving drunk.

Comment: @Jim Getting to this comment after all the others made me immediately think of *driving drunkly*. I paused for a couple of seconds, and then corrected it to *driving drunkenly*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [any of these search results](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Drop+ly).

Comment: Noun=stupidity. Adjective=stupid. Adverb=stupidly. I would dispute the assertion that _stupidly_ is 'hardly used'. _Stupidness_ is not a conventional word.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'd say "Driving drunkenly" is "in the manner of a drunk person" (swerving and all, but not necessarily under the influence of alcohol), "driving drunk" is "while intoxicated". I'd say this is parallel to the "stupid" example: "driving stupidly" is "making many silly mistakes", while "driving stupid" is "while being unintelligent". The last one is pragmatically weird because we don't typically consider IQ as being a temporary condition like drunkenness is (though you can metaphor it into "despite being unintelligent").

Comment: While "stupid" may be used as an adverb in some contexts, it's not "proper" speech to do so.

Answer (score 1):

So we see a total of four uses of the word ***stupid*** (*adjective*, *adverb*, and two *nouns*). Other words in question are ***stupidly*** (*adverb*), ***stupidity*** (*noun*), and ***stupidness*** (*noun*).

The **Proper English uses** are *stupid (adj.), stupidly (adv.),* and *stupidity (n.):*

> *adj.* ... **1** unintelligent; foolish (*a stupid fellow*). **2** typical of stupid persons (*put in a stupid place*). **3** uninteresting or boring. **4** in a state of stupor or lethargy. **5** obtuse; lacking in sensibility. [*Derivations:*] **stu·pid·i·ty** /-íditee/ *n.* (*pl.* **-ies**). **stu·pid·ly** *adv.*
>
> ——*The Illustrated Oxford Dictionary*, DK Publishing (1998)

**Colloquial** and **slang uses** are *stupid (adv.)* and *stupid (n. 1 & 2)*:

> **Adverb**
>
> **stupid** (*comparative* more stupid, *superlative* most stupid)
>
> 1. (slang) Extremely.
>
>    *My gear is stupid [fly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fly#Adjective).*
>
> [...]
>
> **Noun**
>
> **stupid** (*countable and uncountable, plural* stupids)
>
> 1. A stupid person; a fool.
> 2. (*colloquial, uncountable*) The state or condition of being stupid.
>
>    *His stupid knows no bounds.*
>
> ——[Wiktionary.com](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stupid#Adverb)

While I can't find it in many online dictionaries, Wiktionary hits the nail on the head here: The slang adverb *stupid* means "extremely." The sentence sounds off when applied to verbs, like in "He's driving stupid" (the better phrasing being "He's driving stupidly"). *Stupid* works better as an **adverb for adjectives**: "That's stupid cool," "He's stupid bad at driving," or even "He's a stupid good driver."

As for our colloquial nouns, one might call someone *a stupid* just like you say. It can also sometimes be like a synonym for *stupidity*. "You can't fix stupid," "The air of stupid in this room is so thick it's almost tangible." (In my town, this one might take a second thought to understand what you're saying.)

As for ***stupidness* vs. *stupidity***, this was answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273711/stupidity-or-stupidness-what-should-i-use-can-i-use-either-of-them). Being constructed with similarly defined suffices, the two words are synonymous. *Stupidity* has long-standing acceptance. *Stupidness* is rarely and endemically preferred. I have no evidence for it being used outside the West Indies.